# ptrace: STEPINTO returns breakpoint signal

Tags: linux, debugging, breakpoints, ptrace

Yet another ptrace question:

The process is paused for the initial SIGTRAP, then i call ptrace with STEPINTO to step the next instruction. After the ptrace call, i call waitpid(...) and sure enough it does receive a SIGTRAP signal! Great!

however, when i examine the siginfo_t structure by calling

```
 ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, &siginfo)
```

the fields are as follows:

```
 si_signo = SIGTRAP
 si_code = 1
```

however, 1 is the signal code for a breakpoint. No breakpoint was hit in this case:

```
/* `si_code' values for SIGTRAP signal.  */
enum
{
  TRAP_BRKPT = 1,       /* Process breakpoint.  */
# define TRAP_BRKPT TRAP_BRKPT
  TRAP_TRACE            /* Process trace trap.  */
# define TRAP_TRACE TRAP_TRACE
};
```

What's going on?

All calls involved return success (0) and errno is 0, too.

edit: so what happens when i hit a real 0xCC breakpoint?
A SIGTRAP is fired and the si_code field is 0x80 ! 0x80 isnt even defined for  SIGTRAP! :(